# Flatlist adds multiple times the same items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make a small App to count Calories using React Navigation and React Redux. The goal is for the user to search an item in the `SearchBar`, tap in one of the food items which will move him to the `Food` page, and from that page tap on the `checkmark` to add the food in the `Flatlist` and send him back to the Main Screen (`Diet`). I'm using the state `showList` to show the `Flatlist` when tapping on the `SearchBar` then use React Navigation to navigate and send `params` to the Food screen and then use React Redux to update the global state `foodList` and add that item in the main `Flatlist` (in Diet screen) through the checkmark `Button`, I also use `getDerivedStateFromprops` to update the state `foodList` in the Diet screen. The problem is that when I add an item, it adds multiple times the same item and when I add a new one it adds again a lot of times the same items. I used to bring the params back to the Main screen using React Navigation but I thought I could fix this problem by using Redux, and I was wrong because the problem is still there.

**Main Screen**

```
class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.camera = null;
    this.barcodeCodes = [];
    this.state = {
      showList: false,
      data: [],
      searchValue: "",
      foodList: [],
      foodName: null,
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props?.foodList) {
      return {
        foodList: [...state.foodList, ...props.foodList],
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  updateSearch = (value) => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: value });
    if (value.trim() !== "") {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?ingr=${value}&app_id=2626c70d&app_key=0c0f87ae4e5437621363ecf8e7ea80ae&page=20`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({ data: res.data.hints });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        });
    }
  };


return (

      <SearchBar
            platform={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios" : "android"}
            placeholder="Search Food..."
            onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
            value={searchValue}
            onFocus={() => this.setState({ showList: true })}
            onCancel={() => this.setState({ showList: false })}
          />
          {this.state.showList === true ? (
            <View>
             <FlatList
              data={this.state.data.map((item) => item.food)}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <ListItem>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() =>
                      {this.props.navigation.navigate("Food", {
                        id: item.foodId,
                        brand: item.brand,
                        title: item.label,
                        calories: item.nutrients.ENERC_KCAL,
                        protein: item.nutrients.PROCNT,
                        fat: item.nutrients.FAT,
                        carbs: item.nutrients.CHOCDF,
                      }),
                      this.setState({showList:false})
                    }

                    }
                  >
                    <View>
                      <Text>{item.label}</Text>
                      <Text>{item.brand}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </ListItem>
              )}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.foodId}
            />

   ) : (
               <FlatList                                 ///Main Flatlist
                      data={this.state.foodList}
                      renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <View>
                          <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => {
                              this.props.navigation.navigate(
                                "FoodNotModifible",
                                {
                                  title: item.foodName,
                                  calories: item.calories,
                                  carbs: item.carbs,
                                  protein: item.protein,
                                  fat: item.fat,
                                  numberServings: item.numberServings,
                                  servingSize: item.servingSize,
                                }
                              );
                            }}
                          >
                            <Text>{item.foodName}</Text>
                              <Text>
                                {item.calories}
                              </Text>
                              <MaterialIcons name="arrow-forward-ios" />
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                          </View>
                      )}
                      keyExtractor={item => item.foodId}
                    />

);
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(store){
  return{
      foodList: store.userState.foodList
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Diet);
```

**Food Screen**

```
class Food extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          foodList: this.props.foodList,
      }
    }

    submitFood = () => {
        let foodList= this.state.foodList;
        foodList.push({
             foodId: this.props.route.params.foodId,
             foodName: this.props.route.params.title,
             calories: this.props.route.params.calories,
             carbs: this.props.route.params.carbs,
             protein: this.props.route.params.protein,
             fat: this.props.route.params.fat,
        });
        this.props.updateFoodList(foodList);
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Diet");
      };

   render() {
    const { brand, title, calories, protein, carbs, fat, foodId } = this.props.route.params;
        return (

          <Container>
            <Header>
                <Left>
                <Button transparent>
                    <Icon
                    name="arrow-back"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
                    />
                </Button>
                </Left>
                <Body>
                <Title>Add Food</Title>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                <Button transparent>
                    <Icon
                    name="checkmark"
                    onPress={this.submitFood}
                    />
                </Button>
                </Right>
            </Header>
            <View>
                <Text>
                 {JSON.stringify(title)}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                 {JSON.stringify(brand)}
                </Text>
            </View>
```

**Redux Function**

```
export const updateFoodList = (foodList) => {
  return { type: ADD_FOOD, payload: foodList}
}
```

Comment: This might be the problem `foodList: [...state.foodList, ...props.foodList]` you have a spread operator to append data. Make sure you have the correct condition to append-only when required.

Comment: I am new generally to programming, how can I fix that?

Comment: You need to add conditions in such a way that the new data is appended only when required. `props?.foodList` is not correct check with the previous state to compare for state change and set the value to the state it will solve.

Comment: If you are new I would suggest trying react hook it will be easier for you to learn and with very little code. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html